# How remove of Like Box in class ._4s7c the "BORDER" to 0 or none

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I tried to use this `.fb-social-plugin.fb-like-box.fb_iframe_widget._4s7c` this but it didn’t work. Can people help me?

I don't know if it’s possible.

I think have some CSS trick, but I don't know how it works.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <style>
 .facebook-like-box
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative; /* For IE7 Compatibility */
}

.facebook-like-box .inner
{
    margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;
}

.fb-social-plugin.fb-like-box.fb_iframe_widget._4s7c{border: none !important;}

 </style>
  <div class="facebook-like-box">
    <div class="inner">
        <!-- Facebook Plugin Code --->
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
        <fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/bolaooss" 
        width="250" height="250" 
        colorscheme="light" show_faces="true" 
        stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>
        <!-- End Facebook Plugin Code -->
    </div>
</div>

<fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/bolaooss" 
    width="254" height="254" 
    colorscheme="light" show_faces="true" 
    stream="false" header="false">
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add tag `show_border="false"`

```
<fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/bolaooss" 
width="254" height="254" 
colorscheme="light" show_faces="true" 
stream="false" header="false" show_border="false">
```